# Password Encryption with Fernet

Tags: python, password-encryption, fernet

I am new in python and I am doing these kind of little projects so that I can build myself.
This is a little project which will only add and view the username and passwords with a master password. I was able to add username and passwords with encrypted the passwords in the file. But to view the passwords it shows me two problems in 23 and 39 line. And also the master password is not working.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

'''
def write_key():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    with open("key.key", "wb") as key_file:
        key_file.write(key)'''

def load_key():
    file = open("key.key", "rb")
    key = file.read()
    file.close()
    return key

master_pwd = input("What is the master password? ")
key = load_key() + master_pwd.encode()
fer = Fernet(key)

def view():
    with open('passwords.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            data = line.rstrip()
            user, passw = data.split("|")
            print("User:", user, "| Password:",
                  fer.decrypt(passw.encode()).decode())

def add():
    name = input("Account name: ")
    pwd = input("Input password: ")

    with open('passwords.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(name + "|" + fer.encrypt(pwd.encode()).decode() + "\n")

while True:
    mode = input("Would you like to add a new password or view existing  ones?(Add/View):\nOtherwise press 'Q' to Quit: \n").lower()
    if mode == "q":
        break
    elif mode == "view":
        view()
    elif mode == "add":
        add()
    else:
        print("Invalid mode.")
        continue
```

[The problems are shown in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ28a.png)

Comment: Did you try printing `data` before `split`?

Comment: Yes. and that was good with no problem

Comment: The code as given works fine for me.

Comment: Same here, works for me.

Comment: Then why it is not working for me? I have pip-cryptography installed and updated and running the code in pycharm.
And by the way the adding is fine. The problem is in viewing the passwords.